# Show event slot codeigniter calendar

Tags: codeigniter, calendar

I have used codeigniter calendar

http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/calendar.html

its working fine if we have to select single day event, but there is no way for slot selection.

Like want to show selected day then pass data : day numbers 3, 7, 13, and 26

but what if want to select date : from 2nd Jan to 6th Jan

then how to pass start date and end date of event?

[image]

Comment: how can i build like this calendar? will you help me?

Answer (score 0):

You can use function like this one:

```
function generate_block($start, $end, $link){
    $block = array();
    for ($x = $start; $x <= $end; $x++) {
        $block[$x] = $link;
    }
    return $block;
}
```

And invoke it this way:

```
$data = $this->generate_block(2, 6, 'http://example.com/news/article/2006/26/');
echo $this->calendar->generate(2006, 1, $data);
```

Above function should be improved to check input parameters (not null, not negative, start equal or less than end, start and end do not exceed number of days in month, etc).
Also, it would be nice to alter calendar template to paint calendar cells in single block into same colour.

Comment: thanks for your kind help, what i want is added image in question, want to create event with start date and end date,so your code is for the same?

Comment: Ivan Jovovic : please can you update me with my queries?

Comment: @Er.KT: Looking at your image - I do not think that CI calendar supports that out of box. You will have either to heavily change core of CI calendar or use some third-party calendar library (which is way easier than first option).